# Woocommerce product price filter is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone who experience this kind of error?

[image]

If so how did you fix it?

Comment: can you share link here?

Comment: https://litdistributions.com/shop/

Comment: can you put your jquery code to display filter values?

Comment: I used only the default price filter provided by woocommerce.

Comment: you need to update some code on change slider function in /woocommerce-currency-switcher/js/price-slider.js?ver=4.9.8 file

Comment: The information to replicate this issue must be in the question itself, and the brief info here is not nearly enough for a WooCommerce dev to be able to help. Please do some debugging (e.g. in your Network tab - is everything loaded and returning 200 results? and in your JS tab - are there any fatal JS errors?). Once you have done that, you can provide that information here - it may help uncover your problem